# Sql Query to retain max 2 duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

```
      Name   ID    Date
      Dave  | 123 | 1-2-2011
      Jim   | 123 | 1-3-2011
      Mike  | 123 | 1-10-2011
      Bill  | 111 | 1-2-2011
      Henry | 222 | 1-3-2011
      Larry | 222 | 1-4-2011
```

I need a delete query to reduce this to:

```
     Jim   | 123 | 1-3-2011
     Mike  | 123 | 1-10-2011
     Bill  | 111 | 1-2-2011
     Larry | 222 | 1-4-2011
```

i.e. I want to keep the two latest records for each ID.

I tried this:

```
Delete FROM UserTable a
WHERE
Date <> (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM UserTable b WHERE a.ID = b.ID) 
AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM UserTable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

but this retains only the latest 1 unique records.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking.  What does "2 latest records which are duplicated" mean?  What defines a  record as "unique" (shouldn't all records by unique in some manner? I don't understand why Dave's record is not in the output while Bill's is.

Comment: Including your query in the question would be helpful

Comment: I think the post is asking for a set which consists of the most recent 2 entries (col3) for each (col2).  I'm not sure what the subject has to do with this though;  as 5 could vary based on number of records...

Comment: Dates adhere to a particular format in SQL. This isn't it.

Comment: Oh k..sorry for making it not clear  .if i say the duplication factor as 2,i shuld be able to retain only the unique records(ID here)
and the latest 2 records which are duplicate .have to delete all other oldest duplicate records                                       

the column fileds are Name,ID,updated time.

Comment: I think this is what you're after: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7ccbe/25/0 Kinda wish mysql supported window data though this would have been easier to read with it `Select Col1, col2, Col3 from (
SELECT foo.*, 
@curRank:=if(@col2 = col2, @CurRank + 1, 1)   LimitBy,
@col2:=if(@col2 = col2, @col2, col2)   ctrlBreak
FROM foo, (SELECT @curRank := 0, @col2:=0) b
ORDER BY col2, col3 desc) C
where limitBy < 3
ORDER BY col2, col3` substitute tablename foo for your talbe and col1,col2,col3 for your columns leave anything @variable alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try something of the sort:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM your_TableName) AS T1
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

Comment: How does this limit the results so there are only 2 records for each distinct col2 value?

Answer (score 0):

try using this code below depending on what you want to request try using ASC or DESC

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name,column_name ASC|DESC;
```

Try also reading up on your sql http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: How would this limit the results so that there are only 2 records for each distinct col2 value?

Comment: You can use a max function or greater/less/equals to signs, to limit. and only select the columns you want to call .Hope I understood what you were saying and answered you correctly... you should find more help here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 0):

Partition over can be used to retain more than one duplicate.

```
delete from UserTable 
 where (id, date) in (  
        select id,date from (
           select id,date, 
                  row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as temp
             from UserTable)
        where temp > 2
 );
```

This query adds another column with row number partitioned by the id, ordered by date and then deletes those records which have row number greater than 2.